# php jpgraph barplot with multiple line label

Tags: php, bar-chart, jpgraph

I want to have multiple line label for my barplot.
I have been using `str_replace()` to replace all the whitespace into `\r\n or \n` but none of it works. The label did not break into multiple lines.

Did anyone know how to make it right?

Comment: breaking names && adding "\n" helped me,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747093/6060968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it, it is just some syntax error.

instead of `str_replace(' ', '\n', str)`

i should use `str_replace(' ', "\n", str)`